# Breaking #each loop in handlebar

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I am having a handlebar script code like this inside my ascx file.

```
<script id="ex" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{#each model}}
   {{#if condition}}
  //Need to Break, Dont know how to do that
   {{/if}}
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you have to write your own handler to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass this object it to a javascript function, do the required logic and return it.

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    Handlebars.registerHelper("ifSet", function (model) {        
        var count = 0;
        while (count < model.length) {            
    //    if (logic Condition){
    //      return 'Success';  or Break;             
    //    }
        }
        return;
    });     
</script>

<script id="ex" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{ifSet model}}
</script>
```